# killing the bash interpreter

Tags: command-line, bash, process, grep, ps

Im trying to kill /bin/bash but when I do

```
ps aux | grep "/bin/bash"
```

and I kill the pid associated with it, it gaves me an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also can you tell me what's the result of killing it.

[my shell pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlmeH.png)

Comment: I receive no errors but bash continues to work with new pid

Comment: You are only showing part of the picture. `ps -aux` output is missing plus your kill command. Please include all output.

Comment: I get an error and it changes pid. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The process listed here is the *`grep command`*, not the bash process. The grep process finishes running when the output is produced. Thus you get a error message stating that there's no such process when you try to kill it!

`ps aux` does not include the path in the output, and you search for the complete path - and find nothing.

To find bash processes run

```
ps aux | grep bash
```

Then you can kill the desired `bash` process.

Comment: Thanks man, but It doesn't kill the bash do you know why?

Comment: Because you're not trying to! You are running `kill 2236` - which **was** the pid of the grep that was looking trough the text for you!

Comment: I tried sending the signal 15 with kill and it don't do nothing.Know why?

Comment: Please read my answer again. Then read what you see on screen yourself. Run `ps aux | grep 'bash` and compare it to the the output of `ps aux | grep '/bin/bash'. Do you notice a difference?

Comment: One shows only the /bin/bash while the other shows both of them bash and /bin/bash

Comment: No, one of them shows only the **grep process**. Please read what you actually see on screen.

Comment: The OP may find `pgrep -a bash` more straightforward

Comment: vidarlo yeah but grep is in both of the commands? I don't get it.

Comment: steeldriver this actually works, thanks my man!

Comment: Grep is the command you are running to look for /bin/bash. It includes that command, as /bin/bash is part of that command. But /bin/bash does **not** show up as a process, only as part of the grep. ps aux does not include pathnames, and thus this grep does not match anything but this process.

Comment: vidarlo ok, I see it now